# how to show z belongs to a set of Complex Numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have been given the equation, show that
$$z\bar z + 3(z-\bar z) = 13-12i$$

How would i go about finding $z\in \Bbb C$? I thought to go along the route of:

$$z\bar z = \mathrm{Re}(z)^2+\mathrm{Im}(z)^2$$

and

$$z-\bar z = 2\mathrm{Im}(z)$$

But I like to picture where to go but i cannot see where to go to show that the equation $= 13-12i$.

Do i have to assume that $z = 13-12i$?
I cant put my finger on where to go.

Help would be much appreciated.
sorry that my html isnt to good.

Comment: This question is very ill-phrased and poorly formatted. What's there to prove here? Do you mean "solve the equation", i.e., get the complex solutions to the given equation? Also, I don't see how the `education` tag is relevant here.

Comment: I've reformatted your question in MathJax. See that I haven't changed anything essential please. [Here's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a very helpful post to help you write formatted math on this site.

Answer (score 3):

The equation actually contains two equations, one for real part and the other for imaginary part.

Let $z=x+yi$, then
$$x^2+y^2+6yi=13-12i\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\left\{
\begin{align}
&x^2+y^2=13\\
&6yi=-12i
\end{align}
\right.$$